# HTML Reports not visible in Jenkins Dashboard

Tags: jenkins-plugins, html-reports-jenkins

In my Jenkins, I have installed HTML Publisher.

[image: Added in post build section]

After adding this I have restarted Jenkins and when I am checking Pipeline(project)
**Html reports**  is not visible on Dashboard.

This is my dashboard view
[image]

**NOTE**
I have tried the same set up in the different project and there it was working perfectly.

Comment: Not sure what you want, but you could name the ranges.

Comment: my question is can I get multiple ranges by providing only unique key. In the above case, a unique id is 1  and 2 and I need data available in ranges

Comment: Just place the unique id in its own column.  Then you can use ***AutoFilter*** to select a specific id and display only those rows associated with that id.

Comment: If I understand your question, then name the ranges, so "one" would be your range A5:F6 etc Don't think excel will accept "1" as a valid name...

Comment: are the associated ranges always 6 rows by 5 columns?  Are they always immediately adjacent to the ID?  Is the ID part of the range?  Can the ID number be filled in so its beside each row in the range?

Answer (score 1):

make a list of indexes and the ranges

There can be two options to use the range

- Apply some formula on that range
- Display the values in that range

I have inserted examples for both as below

[image]

In E1 you can enter 1 ,2 or 3 (any value from the index and range created list)

Formula in F1 is `=SUM(INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(E1,B1:C4,2,0)))`

this will give a sum of values in range against the index

Entry of 2nd example is in A9, you can enter any index in A9

Formula in B9 is `=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(A9,B1:C4,2,0))`

The trick here is that you have to start selecting the cells where you want to display the range from B9 and go till E10 (or what ever cell is best for you)

Now press F2 and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you make your selections in cell H1 and that all the ranges are 6 rows by 5 columns.  you could define your range using the following formula:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH($H$1,A:A,0):INDEX(F:F,MATCH($H$1,A:A,0)+5)
```

IF you want the ID number to be part of the range, change B:B to A:A

The above formula cannot be used on its own.  However since it defines a range, you can then use it in other formulas that need to work with a range.  IE you could nest it in the AVERAGE function as follows:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(B:B,MATCH($H$1,A:A,0):INDEX(F:F,MATCH($H$1,A:A,0)+5))
```

or use it for the look up range in VLOOKUP

```
=VLOOKUP("Timmy",INDEX(B:B,MATCH($H$1,A:A,0):INDEX(F:F,MATCH($H$1,A:A,0)+5),3,0)
```